Clarification on the symmetry of logarithmic derivatives in "A method for verifying the generalized Riemann hypothesis"
I am reading the paper A method for verifying the generalized Riemann hypothesis by Ghaith A. Hiary, Summer Ireland, and Megan Kyi. On page 8, the authors define the completed $L $-function:
$$\xi_L(s) := \epsilon N^{s/2} \pi^{-sr/2} \prod_{j=1}^r \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2} + \frac{M_j}{2}\right) L(s)
\tag{$*$}\label{484667_star}$$
where $ \epsilon $ is a complex number of modulus 1, $ M_j $ ($1 \leq j \leq r$) are real non-negative numbers, and $N$  is a positive constant. The function $ \xi_L(s) $ extends to an entire function and satisfies the functional equation:
$$
\xi_L(s) = \overline{\xi_L(1 - \overline{s})}.
$$
The paper asserts the following symmetry for the  $k$-th derivative of the logarithm of $ \xi_L $:
$$
\left[\frac{d^k}{ds^k} \log \xi_L(s + \delta) \right]_{s = 0} = (-1)^k \left[\frac{d^k}{ds^k} \log \xi_L(s - \delta) \right]_{s = 1},
$$
where $ \delta $ is a real number.
Could you provide more details or a sketch of the argument that leads to the equation \eqref{484667_star}?
I appreciate any insights or references that could clarify this point!

Please use a high-level tag like "cv.complex-variables". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

For a real function $f(z)$ that satisfies $f(z)=f(a-z)$ for real $z$, one has
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^k}{ds^k}f(s+\delta)=\lim_{-s\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^k}{d(-s)^k}f(-s+\delta)=(-1)^k\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^k}{ds^k}f(s+a-\delta)$$
$$\qquad = (-1)^k\lim_{s\rightarrow a}\frac{d^k}{ds^k}f(s-\delta).$$
In this case $a=1$ and $a,\delta$ are both real, so the complex conjugation has no effect. (The complex $\epsilon$ in the definition of $\xi_L$ drops out of the logarithmic derivative.)

I added "for real $z$" to your first sentence, because $\xi_L(s) = \xi_L(1 - s)$ only holds for real values of $s$. Also, this requires that $\xi_L(s)$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ which I am not sure is satisfied in the OP's situation (I haven't checked).

Actually it is $f(s):=\xi_L(s)/\epsilon$ that maps $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$. This follows from the second display on Page 8 of the quoted paper, and is sufficient for the argument presented.
